# django - get first record for each day

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model Sales with:

- Saler
- Product sold
- Date

I would like to get the first sale for each date and for each saler, how can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the model Posted in the question, the Django ORM query will be:

```
first_sale = Sales.objects.order_by("Saler", "Date").distinct("Saler")
```

Comment: distinct give the first record ? I was thinking about this but can't find anything in the documentation

Comment: yes, you can go ahead and test it. and print and check the queryset returned.
I have a similar use case(considering the same model in the question), instead I had to fetch the latest record for each seller on each date.
So I did this :- 
`latest_sale = Sales.objects.order_by("Saler", "-Date").distinct("Saler")`

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but I would try (I assumed the field for the date of the sale is named `sale_date`, and is of type Datetime):

```
first_sale = Sales.objects.filter(saler=the_saler, sale_date__date=datetime.date(2021, 05, 19)).order_by('sale_date').first()
```

- `filter` will restrict the search to a given saler (`the_saler`), and to a given day (see the `__date` expression: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#date)
- `order_by` and `first` will give you the first of the day.

Comment: Thanks, but with this solution I will have to loop on every date and every saler? I have about 250 dates and 50 salers

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve in the end, you didn't give enough details. But basically, yes. If what you want is some kind of dashboard on your salers and dates, maybe you should create some tables in your database to hold statistics, and fill it once a day. Or create views directly in db. The Django ORM is not, in my opinion, the easiest way to perform this kind of queries.